# How to get the filepath to specific files containing a string?

Tags: bash, path, find

Deep in the subdirectories are a few specific files containing a string that indicates they are the target directory I need. (This concerns creating virtual GPUs, but is beside the point.) I can find the files I need with this command:

```
cat `find ../../devices -name "name"` | grep 8Q
```

which results in this output:

```
GRID T4-8Q
GRID T4-8Q
GRID T4-8Q
GRID T4-8Q
```

but this does not tell me the filepath to those 4 files.

How can I rewrite this command so that it finds these 4 files, but also tells me the filepath?

TIA,
Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`has an `exec` test that can do about anything you want on found files. If the executed command exits with 0 status the test passes. In the command `{}` is replaced with the file name. The command must be terminated with `\;` (there are other terminators with different behaviors but `\;` is what you need here). In your case `grep -q 8Q {} \;` is the command to use. It exits with status 0 if and only if the file contains `8Q`. `find` also has a `printf` test that can print the directory part (`%h`).

You can try:

```
find ../../devices -type f -name "name" -exec grep -q 8Q {} \; -printf '%h\n'
```

If the found file is a real file (`-type f`) and its name is `name` (`-name "name"`) and the file contains `8Q`, then the directory part is printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to all **unique** set of directories containing files that have `8Q` text in them then I suggest following variant of `Renaud's` `find` command.

```bash
find ../../devices -type f -name 'name' -exec grep -qF '8Q' {} + -printf '%h\0' | 
awk -v RS='\0' '!seen[$0]++'
```

PS: Note that both `find` and `awk` have to be `gnu` ones since `-printf` is only supported in `gnu find` and multi-character `RS` is also `gnu awk` specific.